# Разные действия для кнопок формы Spring MVC

Tags: html, spring

Есть две кнопки в двух формах, у каждой формы свое действие. Если я хочу поместить radiobutton, мне нужно это делать в двух формах что бы он применялся к любой из кнопок. Вопрос в том, возможно ли сделать в одной форме две кнопке с разными действиями что бы radiobutton не дублировать.

```html
<spring:form method="post" modelAttribute="rusengJSP" action="indexrus">

  <spring:button>Russian</spring:button>
  <br/>
  <spring:radiobutton path="mf" value="M" label="M" />
  <spring:radiobutton path="mf" value="F" label="F" />
</spring:form>

<spring:form method="post" modelAttribute="rusengJSP" action="indexeng">

  <spring:button>English</spring:button>
  <spring:radiobutton path="mf" value="M" label="M" />
  <spring:radiobutton path="mf" value="F" label="F" />
</spring:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать так

**form.jsp**

```
<spring:form method="post" modelAttribute="rusengJSP" action="indexrus">
    <input type="submit" name="action-ru" value="Russian"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="action-en" value="English"/>
    <br/>
    <spring:radiobutton path="mf" value="M" label="M" />
    <spring:radiobutton path="mf" value="F" label="F" />
</spring:form>
```

**SomeController.java**

```
@Controller("/indexrus")
public class SomeController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm() {
        return "form";
    }

    @RequestMapping(params = "action-ru", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void actionRu(@ModelAttribute SomeClass rusengJSP) {
        ...
    }

    @RequestMapping(params = "action-en", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void actionEn(@ModelAttribute SomeClass rusengJSP) {
        ...
    }
}
```